# Convert SPSS string variable to numeric and date

Tags: spss, date-conversion

I have the date variable which is in string format. I need to convert this to numeric or date format. How can I do this?

Example:

```
var1 
2010/07/09
2010/07/16
```

Thanks,
Tanuvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read in the date value as a string, you can use Transform > Date and Time Wizard to convert it to an SPSS date variable.  Although date variables look like dates in various formats, they are actually represented as the number of seconds since 1582 and can consist of calendar and time information.